# parse.com: Recommended permissions for roles and users tables

Tags: permissions, parse-platform, roles

I'm locking down the parse.com database permissions for release of my app. What are the recommended class-level permissions for the Users and Roles tables so that login and ACL still work, but people can't cause any mischief by accessing the tables directly through the rest API? I don't really want to go by trial-and-error when it comes to security, and the documentation doesn't seem to say anything.

I'm tempted to lock them all down except for access through an "Admin" role. Will that interfere with the login or sign-up systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have different Roles. I use a Cloud Code function to automatically grant access to my documents on parse.com. Basically global user can only create an account on user, but cannot read other user data and they aren't allowed to perform CRUD commands on Roles.
Also check that tutorial and guide:
http://blog.parse.com/2014/06/30/parse-security-i-are-you-the-key-master/
https://www.parse.com/docs/data#security

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    // master key has all permissions
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var user = request.user;
    if (user.existed()) { return; }
    // set ACL so only the user himself can see his own data
    user.setACL(new Parse.ACL(user));
    user.save();
    // add user to role
    var roleName = "member";
    var roleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    roleQuery.equalTo("name", roleName);
    roleQuery.first().then(function(role) {
    role.getUsers().add(user);
    // save role
    return role.save();
    });
});
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly you've got create-only on users and nothing on roles, and that allows normal sign-up and login procedures?

Comment: That's correct. In my use case I only needed one kind of user role "member". The above code is always executed when a user is signed up on the client side.